# Is it possible to load .so files from sd instead of packing up them into apk in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This question comes up when my `Apk` file gets its size at **30MB**. Now I try to reduce `apk`'s size but the .so files are really fat.

Is it possible not pack up `.so` file into `apk` but load them from `sd` in Android?

I know it is not safe to use `.so` from `sd` card. Is there any sample project or code snippet for this usage, not caring about the `safety`.

Comment: Even if you can, you shouldn't. Your app would be vulnerable to another app replacing your library with a malicious one.

Comment: Agree to Dan. Go through this link, you will get idea : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/HoKW1aPcK5s

Answer (score 0):

good link please read

http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/C++-dlopen.html

here are a few things to note when loading classes:

You must provide both a creation and a destruction function; you must not destroy the instances using delete from inside the executable, but always pass it back to the module. This is due to the fact that in C++ the operators new and delete may be overloaded; this would cause a non-matching new and delete to be called, which could cause anything from nothing to memory leaks and segmentation faults. The same is true if different standard libraries are used to link the module and the executable.

The destructor of the interface class should be virtual in any case. There might be very rare cases where that would not be necessary, but it is not worth the risk, because the additional overhead can generally be ignored.

If your base class needs no destructor, define an empty (and virtual) one anyway; otherwise you will have problems sooner or later; I can guarantee you that. You can read more about this problem in the comp.lang.c++ FAQ at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/, in section 20.